# How should I set up my repository using GitHub pages so I can see all the files that the site uses?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

Can I set up my repository so that I can see all the files (html and css) that my site uses in the repository while still using the GitHub page generator?

I want to use github.com to maintain my multi page site, without installing Jekyll locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the reason I was not seeing many files was that there was only the index.html that I created using the tutorial at [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/)

The reason I thought there must have been other files was that the theme I picked looked a whole lot better than my helloworld.html

Answer (score 1):

After you create your github repo go to the settings and select the option to host from the docs directory I found this to be the best method to host my websites that way you done have to mess with different branches unless your in to that thing.

It is not required for you to use Jekyll I personally have never used it. It is to wordpress esq.

What you can use instead of Jekyll is a static site generator or spa to precompile your website content add the static content to the doc directory and push your repo.

Github will generate a url for your that will also be available in your settings. You can also add custom domains.

I recomd using a static site generator performance and seo is the reason.

Comment: Thanks, I am sidelined on another project at the moment, but looking forward to checking this out

Comment: It appears that user pages must be built from the master branch. I don't see how I can host from the docs directory.

Comment: from https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/  

"User and Organization Pages that have this type of repository name are only published from the master branch"

Answer (score 0):

If you create a Jekyll website on your local machine in `/some/path/website/`, initialise your Git repository there:

```
cd /some/path/website/
git init
```

Then you can push this to your remote Github repository and all of your files will added and viewable.

I don't think you can initialise a Jekyll website in your remote repository though.

From their [documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/about-github-pages-and-jekyll/):

> Jekyll's simplified build process with GitHub Pages is one of the biggest advantages of using Jekyll instead of other static site generators. GitHub Pages manages your site's build process with a single push to your site's publishing branch. This is Jekyll's build process for managing your site:
>
> - **Push file changes to your pages publishing branch** (my emphasis)
> - GitHub Pages publishes your site.

Comment: Where are you typing these commands and what with?  I am just using Github.  I am not wanting to work locally.

Comment: Hmm ok I'm not sure how you would initialise your Jekyll project then.